# color gradient palette that works well in grayscale

Tags: javascript, jquery, color-scheme

Haven't found a good search term to Google this, so I'm asking here.

I'm making a UI that involves 6 gradations, so I'm trying to achieve a colorful 6 color gradient that will still be a gradient if I'm using a grayscale monitor.

I have a multi monitor setup with color and grayscale and sometimes I drag the browser window between screens.

Any good ways to do this, examples online, or search terms?

Thanks!

Comment: Did the term high-contrast appear anywhere in your search?